# Matching intersections/combinations in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph where green nodes may be linked to one or many red nodes which then link to a set of blue nodes. Red nodes also have an amt property which indicate the minimum number of blue nodes in the set which need to be matched in order to 'satisfy' the red node. A given set of blue nodes 'qualify' for a green node if the set satisfies all of the green node's red neighbours.

Example

[image]

[image]

How would a write a cypher query to return all qualifying green nodes for a given set of blue nodes?

I came up with the following that returns green nodes if all blue nodes of its red neighbours are matched. However, I don't need to match all but rather the amt specified for each red node.

```
MATCH (g:Green)-->(r:Red)-->(b:Blue)
WITH g, COLLECT(b.name) AS myset
WHERE ALL(n in myset where n in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "8", "9", "11"])
RETURN p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to find all the green candidates, and then check them through the red nodes:

```
WITH ["1", "2", "3", "4", "8", "9", "11"] AS blues
MATCH (g:Green)-[:requires]->(r:Red)-[:contains]->(b:Blue) WHERE b.name IN blues

WITH distinct g, blues
MATCH (g)-[:requires]->(r:Red)
OPTIONAL MATCH (r)-[:contains]->(b:Blue) WHERE b.name IN blues

WITH g, r, size(collect(DISTINCT b)) AS bCount
WITH g, collect([r.amt, bCount]) AS test
WITH g WHERe all(t IN test WHERE t[0] <= t[1])
RETURN g
```

Comment: Note that it may be a bit better to collect the blue nodes, then in the OPTIONAL MATCH use an IN check for the nodes themselves rather than doing this with `b.name`. It will save from having to do property access.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Yes, you are right - there is something to optimize if desired))

Comment: I just realized, bCount counts the blue nodes connected to the red node and compares it to red node.amt however what is required is bCount should be the amt of bluenodes the rednode has in common with the input. eg if r1 is connected to [1, 2, 3]  r1.amt is 2 and r2 is connected to [2, 4], r2.amt =1 then with the input [1, 2, 4] then both red notes are satisfied  because r1 has 2  at least nodes in common (r1.amt) with in the input and r2 has at least 1 node (r2.amt) in common with the input.

Answer (score 0):

This query should return the `Green` nodes whose "required" `Red` nodes *all* have at least their individually required `amt` of "contained" `Blue` nodes:

```
MATCH (g:Green)-[:requires]->(r:Red)
WITH g, r, SIZE((r)-[:contains]->(:Blue)) AS cnt
WITH g, COLLECT({r: r, cnt: cnt}) AS data
WHERE ALL(d IN data WHERE d.cnt >= d.r.amt)
RETURN g;
```

Comment: But how does take input? The query should take a collection of blue nodes and return all green nodes which can satisfy their requirements from the blue nodes in the the the set given.